# Removing 'words' contained in strings with non-alphanumeric characters?

Tags: php, regex, nlp

What is the recommended method in PHP for removing 'words' in strings with non-alphanumeric characters please?

```
$string = "Test let's test 123. https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ EOTest.";
```

desired result:

```
"Test test 123. EOTest.";
```

Method 1 - regex
Method 2 - explode(), foreach() and str_replace or preg_replace

Comment: use explode function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `preg_split`, `preg_grep`, and `implode` functions, like so:

```
$string = "Test let's test 123. https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ EOTest.";
$words = preg_split('/\s+/', $string); // split on one or more spaces
$filter = preg_grep('/^[A-Za-z\d.]+$/', $words); // allow dot, letters, and numbers
$result = implode(' ', $filter); // turn it into a string
print_r($result); // -> Test test 123. EOTest.
```

I hope that helps!